# How to not let jq interpret the newline character when exporting to CSV

Tags: json, jq, export-to-csv

I want to convert the following JSON content stored in a file tmp.json

```
{
    "results": [
        [
           {
               "field": "field1",
               "value": "value1-1"
           },
           {
               "field": "field2",
               "value": "value1-2\n"
           }
        ],
        [
           {
               "field": "field1",
               "value": "value2-1"
           },
           {
               "field": "field2",
               "value": "value2-2\n"
           }
        ]
    ]
}
```

into a CSV output

```
"field1","field2"
"value1-1","value1-2\n"
"value2-1","value2-2\n"
```

When I use this `jq` command, however,

```
 cat tmp.json | jq -r '.results | (first | map(.field)), (.[] | map(.value)) | @csv'
```

I get this result:

```
"field1","field2"
"value1-1","value1-2
"
"value2-1","value2-2
"
```

How should the `jq` command be written to get the desired CSV result?

Comment: @Inian, preferrably, I want to quote each field so it can easily be viewed in Excel. `"value1-1","value1-2\n"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a jq-only solution, you can use `gsub("\n"; "\\n")`. I'd go with something like this:

```
.results
| (.[0] | map(.field)),
  (.[]  | map( .value | gsub("\n"; "\\n")))
| @csv
```

Using your JSON and invoking this with the -r command line option yields:

```
"field1","field2"
"value1-1","value1-2\n"
"value2-1","value2-2\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

If newlines are the only thing you can handle, maybe you can do a string replacement.

```
cat tmp.json | jq -r '.results | (first | map(.field)), (.[] | map(.value) | map(gsub("\\n"; "\\n"))) | @csv'
```

Comment: @rchrome, this causes a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` in my CentOS7 machine. Not sure why.

Comment: hmm interesting, it works on my ubuntu 16.04 machine with jq version 1.5.1

Comment: @rchrome, the edited solution now works in my CentOS7 machine. thank you.